# What is the normal vector to the plane ax+by+cz=d?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

If d=0, then we obviously see that the equation is the Euclidean inner product with (a,b,c) and (x,y,z) that equals zero - and so (a,b,c) is the normal vector to the plane.

What if $d \ne 0$?

Then I don't have the same intuitive way of finding the normal - the "inner product" wouldn't be 0, and we couldn't conclude the orthogonality of the vectors.

Thanks,

Comment: It is still (a, b, c), which can be shown by cross product.

Comment: It is the same vector. Both planes are  parallel.

Comment: Hi @bernard, how can we tell the planes are parallel?  Thanks,

Comment: I believe *d* is the distance of the plane from the origin, multiplied by the magnitude of the vector |(*a*,*b*,*c*)|.  Changing *d* translates the plane, but does not rotate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $(x_0,y_0z_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ are any two points in the plane $ax+by+cz=d$, we have $ax_0+by_0+cz_0=ax_1+by_1+cz_1$, whence
$$a(x_1-x_0)+b(y_1-y_0)+c(z_1-z_0)=0.$$

Comment: Ok got it - thanks so much @bernard :-)

Comment: It's an especially nice reminder to sometimes switch from thinking of vectors as points in space and vice versa ... especially in some of the 4-dimensional plane equation problems :-)

Comment: Excellent, thank you. It is worth reading the above, with this answer if anyone has any confusion: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4400640/379107

Comment: Perhaps it might be worth adding another line separating the constants on the other side of the equation>

Answer (score 7):

Since the gradient $\nabla f(x,y,z)$ is perpendicular to the [level sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set#Level_sets_versus_the_gradient) of $f(x,y,z)$, we can use the gradient $\nabla(ax+by+cz-d)=(a,b,c)$ which is perpendicular to the plane.

Comment: Oh this is so freakin cool, @robjohn :-) I always really enjoy your work on MSE.  Thanks so much!